# Will the king messiah be a prophet?

Tags: messiah, nevua-prophecy

By the phrase "king messiah," I am referring to the individual who is expected to come and restore the kingdom of David. (For example, the exact individual that Rambam writes about in [this portion](http://www.chabad.org/library/moshiach/article_cdo/aid/101744/jewish/Laws-Concerning-Kings-and-the-Messiah.htm) of the Mishneh Torah.)

Again, will the king messiah be a prophet? If so, please cite the scripture in the Tanakh and/ or the *halakha*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Rambam ([Teshuvah 9:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=1&hilchos=5&perek=9&halocha=2&hilite=)) says he will be a prophet almost as great as Mosheh Rabbeinu.

Comment: @b a, I upvoted you because you did indeed give a reference from *halakha*. Now, would you happen to know why Rambam says that the king messiah would be a prophet in the first place? From reading that passage in *Hilkhot Teshuva*, I could not find an actual *pasuk* that makes such an explicit claim. How about you? Do you know of one?

Comment: Well, @b a, you answered the question as asked. It is only fair that I award you appropriately. If, however, you know of an actual pasuk, please share. Thanks.

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 The Migdal Oz, quoting Ramban, says it's a tradition. I saw that the [Mishnas Ya'akov on the Rambam](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=107988&rid=451) ties it to a dispute in the gemara. But I don't think there's a scriptural source, as far as I know.

Comment: @b a, it seems we responded at the same time. I do think after some brief research that there may be a scriptural basis, but it must be inferred; it's not explicit. Hopefully @Double AA will allow me to ask another question based on this inference. If you wish, please respond and offer your opinion to my new thread if it remains open.

Comment: @h3br3w Why would I close your follow up question? I haven't closed this question and I see no reason to do so.

Comment: @Double AA, only because they may be so similar. No other reason. =)

Comment: What's the Rambam's makor for this?

Comment: @Yehoshua See what I wrote in the third comment from the top.

Comment: @ba I read through the mafarshim and saw that. Thanks. This shows a makor for how the Rambam could say such a thing (and why it wouldn't conflict with the gemorah over there since it's taking sides in the maklokes.) However it doesn't really establish a makor.

Comment: For what it's worth, also towards the end of [Igeret Teiman](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/mekorot/teyman1-2.htm), the Rambam says "שהמשיח נביא גדול מאוד, וגדול מכל הנביאים מלבד משה רבנו ע"ה"( my translation: "... that the _Mashiach_ [wil be] a great prophet, and greater than all the prophets except _Moshe Rabenu_ , peace be upon him").

Answer (score 6):

- **Isaiah 52:13**

  > הנה ישכיל עבדי ירום ונשא וגבה מאד
- Tanchuma Toldot 14

  > ירום מאברהם.
  >   ונשא מיצחק. 
  >   וגבה מיעקב. 
  >   ירום מאברהם. שנאמר: (בראשית יד) הרמותי ידי אל ה'. 
  >   ונשא ממשה, שאמר (במדבר יא) כי תאמר אלי שאהו בחיקך, 
  >   וגבה כמלאכי השרת, שנאמר: (יחזקאל א) וגבותם מלאות עיניים. 
  >   לכך נאמר: מי אתה הר הגדול, וממי הוא יוצא מזרובבל.
- Rambam Teshuvah 9:2

  > נביא גדול הוא קרוב למשה רבינו
- Rosh Hashanah 21a

  > (קהלת יב, י) בקש קהלת למצוא דברי חפץ בקש קהלת להיות כמשה יצתה בת קול ואמרה לו וכתוב יושר דברי אמת (דברים לד, י) ולא קם נביא עוד בישראל כמשה וחד אמר בנביאים לא קם במלכים קם אלא מה אני מקיים בקש קהלת למצוא דברי חפץ בקש קהלת לדון דינין שבלב שלא בעדים ושלא בהתראה יצתה ב"ק ואמרה לו וכתוב יושר דברי אמת (דברים יז, ו) על פי שנים עדים וגו':
- Sanhedrin 93b

  > במשיח כתיב דמורח ודאין

In his edition of the Tanchuma, Rabbi Shlomo Buber quotes מהר"ץ חיות who asks in אגרת בקורת
(דף ה ע"ד) that there is no known source for the Rambam's statement that Mashiach will be close to Moses in prophecy; in fact the only known similar statement in Chazal says the contrary. In Tanchuma it is written that Mashiach will be greater than Moses.

In an effort to solve both מהר"ץ חיות's question and the question what is the source of the Rambam, the Lubavitcher Rebbe [points out](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14929&st=&pgnum=264&hilite=) that in the traditional version the Tanchuma actually goes through two sets of individuals whom Mashiach will be superior to; Abraham, Isaac and Jacob, and Abraham, Moses and the ministering angels, while in Buber's [Tanchuma](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/tanhumabereshit/tanhumabereshit07.pdf) and what מהר"ץ חיות quotes only the second set is mentioned.

In the first set Moses is not mentioned and in the second he is. This may be because with regard to prophecy Mashiach is not greater than Moses (first set), as he **can not** be greater (as per Deut. 34:10 according to first opinion in Rosh Hashanah 21a above), only in the aspect of kingship is Mashiach greater (second set). Mashiach will "smell and judge," (Sanhedrin 93b above). Even Solomon was turned down and he was only given permission to judge with witnesses (Rosh Hashanah 21a above), but King Mashiach's authority will be such that he will be able to smell and judge.)

According to this, the scriptural source for Mashiach being a prophet is **Isaiah 52:13**.

Answer (score 2):

The Talmud (Sanhedrin 93A) deduces from Yishayahu 11:3 that Moshiach will judge using his sense of smell.

As quoted [here](http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/highlights-of-moshiach/10.htm#t55):

> the Talmud describes Moshiach as a person who will judge with his sense of smell, as is written, "and he shall be animated - v'haricho (power of smell) with the fear of G-d." Said Rava: This means he will be able to detect the truth of a person's statement and will truthfully judge who is guilty, as is written - "not after the sight of his eyes shall he judge."

I would think that that indicates a certain level of prophecy. However, that source says that this is an aspect of his kingship, and not his prophecy.

Comment: Thank you, sir. It is an interesting aspect of his personality, for sure. But, could you elaborate why you believe that it "indicates a certain level of prophecy"? How would that particular statement relate to prophecy (i.e., in what way")?

Comment: I would say being able to read peoples thoughts falls under the category of Ruach Hakodesh, which is a level of prophecy.

Comment: @Menachem Ruach Hakodesh and Nevuah are not the same. See for example Kuzari 1:87, Moreh Nevuchim 2 Chapter 45, Rabbeinu Behaye Deut. 32:8. Abarbanel Ezekiel 2:2, and Daniel 1:1. All in this [link](http://www.aspaklaria.info/200_RESH/%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%97%20%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93%D7%A9.htm).