# Do Jews believe that the messiah will be a prophet?

Tags: messiah

Is there a normative belief in orthodox Judaism that the messiah **must** also be a prophet? If so what is the source for this belief?

Comment: Welcome to MY, and thanks for asking this interesting question. Hope to see you around!

Comment: Hey there. Your question was marked as a duplicate -- check out the answers [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22814/5323)! Hope you enjoy them :)