# Will Messiah ben Josef be a prophet?

Tags: messiah, nevua-prophecy, shevatim-12-tribes

Is Messiah ben Josef, the war messiah, the messiah from the 10 lost tribes, expected to be a prophet? If not, how is he supposed to wage war in preparation for the messianic kingdom?

Comment: What does prophecy have to do with waging war

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Kieran and thanks for this first question. Hope to see you around!

Comment: Seems inconsistent. Moshiach Ben Yosef or Messiah the son of Joseph.

Comment: Who has successfully waged war against Israel enemies who wasn't counted as a prophet?

Comment: Also, how can someone be prophesied, like Messiah ben Josef, and then not be a prophet when they fulfil prophecy?

Comment: Related question about the Mashiach (ben David): https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22814/1569. I don't think the Rambam mentions the Mashiach ben Yosef at all in Mishne Tora

Comment: @kieran Otniel. Ehud. Shamgar. Gideon. Samson. Hezekiah. etc. All them fought successful wars without being prophets.

Comment: Why is Deborah counted as a prophet and those other Judges aren't? Obviously, these people might have been prophets. Samson was obviously a prophet, how could he have God's strength and cry onto the Lord to knock the temple without talking to God?

Comment: @kieten anyone can talk to God. A prophet is someone who God talks to.

Comment: But how do you define what it means for God to talk to someone? God replied to Samson by restoring his strength to allow him to knock down the temple, so why isn't he a prophet? Can God reply to someone by allowing them to win wars for him?

Comment: What is _the messiah from the 10 lost tribes_ all about? Source, please.